# Variable out of EXACT selection - Javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code here:

```
if (!window.TextSelect) {
    TextSelect = {};
}

TextSelect.Selector = {};
TextSelect.Selector.getSelected = function () {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

TextSelect.Selector.mouseup = function () {
    var st = TextSelect.Selector.getSelected();
    if (st != '') {
        $("#paragraphs div").removeClass("selected");

        goodoldst = st.toString();

        quoteExist = '';
        for (i = 0; i < assocs.length; i++) {

            if (st.toString().indexOf(assocs[i]) >= 0) {

                quoteExist = quoteExist + '1';

            } else {
                quoteExist = quoteExist + '0';
            }

        }

        console.log(quoteExist)

        if (quoteExist.indexOf('1') >= 0) {

            alert('ALREADY IN DATABASE!!!')

        } else {

            newst = '<div class="selected">' + st + '</div>';
            newvalue = paraval.replace(st, newst);
            $('#paragraphs').html(newvalue);
            if (newst != '' && $('.explanation').css('display') == 'none') {
                $('.explanation').toggle();
            }

            $('#newDescr').html(' SELECTED TEXT FORM <textarea id="thedescr" ></textarea><br><button onClick="sendNewDescr()">SUBMIT!</button>');
            if ($("#annotation").css("display") == "block") {
                $("#annotation").toggle();
            }

            makeitglob(goodoldst);

            $.post('ajax.php?q=a', {
                newstajax: newst
            }).done(function (data) {
                //$('.explanation').html(data);

            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I select some text, if I have that specific selection before, it selects the FIRST occurrence of that selection, not what I have selected. The big problem is when I select a letter (let's say " D " ). Instead of having the letter D selected from the paragraph, the D from the tag DIV gets selected. I want to get the EXACT selection, not the first occurrence. Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/ try this. Its the same problem. If i select the last "text", then click on highlight, the last one gets selected. I want the one I selected to get highlited, even if it is the LAST one or one from the middle. by text i mean the word "text"

What I am trying to do is have a system like "Genius" ( http://screen.genius.com/Steven-kloves-harry-potter-and-the-sorcerers-stone-how-to-bottle-fame-annotated )

I want have in the database explanations associated to text from a paragraph....

Anyone??

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of just the selection problem you are trying so solve?  It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: it's Ajax. Can't put it there. I can only provide a link... but I am trying to avoid that.

Comment: Well, it's not the ajax that is the problem, is it?  Remove the post and it should still be able to illustrate the issue.  If people can't reproduce the problem, it's very hard to help you fix it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/ try this. Its the same problem. If i select the last "text", then click on highlight, the last one gets selected. I want the one I selected to get highlited

Comment: Might I make an alternative suggestion?  Why not highlight the selected text with css?  If I understand correctly, you are getting the selected text and then going back to the same control to highlight it.  Is the selected div important or is this really just a style change of the selection?

Comment: because I am sending that to PHP. I want exactly that one to go to the database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Range` object returned by `getRangeAt()` contains a `startOffset` and `endOffset` which are the start/end indices of your selection in the string.

See this fiddle for an example of using the offset: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/8/

Comment: works great! But... if I select only a letter from a word then I select another letter from the same word, that second letter goes to the start of the paragraph. why so? This is so close to what I am looking for!

Comment: The issue was that the offset is calculated from the previous node, not the start of the original text block. So when we insert a span node, then every selection beyond the previous one will count the offset from the span, not the start of the text. 

Here is a fiddle if you don't care about preserving the selection: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/8/

If you do, it's a good deal more tricky because you need to merge the contents of the spans.

Comment: I don't really understand. what do you mean by "preserve contents of the spans" ? I Need to store this selection in a database then send it back to Javascript

Comment: Solved all my problems. Thanks soooo much!

Comment: I am trying to make it work on "mouseup" instead on "click". It is working the first time, then it is no longer working. Why so?

Comment: I am having a little problem. If I select another "span" or if my selection includes something I have already selected, I get the some other text selected (but without my class "selected" in it)... 

try to select some text and then select again some text that also includes your previous selection. Thank you so much!

Comment: Fixed that. The problem I have now is that whenever I have a link (in the text that is to be selected), if I click on that link, nothing happens. it just adds "<span class="selected"><span>"  where I have clicked...

Comment: see this please: http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/13/

only that my function is triggered on mouseup, not on click... thanks!

Comment: Hmm, the mouseup event seems to be working fine with the sample. Does the following fiddle work for you? http://jsfiddle.net/zq1dqu3o/17/

Comment: Not really. Do you have an email address? If you can help me in the future, I can also put some $$$ in :)